# Service to return a value produced by event handler

Tags: java, rest

I have a local REST service (embedded Jersey) to get data from locally connected hardware (3M MRZ reader).

The hardware API allows to define event handler to consume data produced by the device. The device should be initialized by the service call.

To get the data from the service, I put it into a variable and try to read it from service method.

```
private String mrzRead = null;

@GET
@Path("/scan")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String scan() {
    initReader();
    String res = null;
    mrzRead = null;
    do {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100L);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        synchronized(this) {
            res = mrzRead;
        }
    } while(res==null);
    mrzRead = null;
    return res;
}

//Event handler
@Override
public void OnFullPageReaderEvent(EventCode aEventType) {
...
    synchronized(this) {
        mrzRead = lCodeline.Data;
    }
...
}
```

This approach does not allow to break waiting cycle from outside (another service call) which is sometimes needed.

Is there a better way to return a value generated by an event handler, from the service?

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to separate value reader and REST service.
Some approaches:

1. Separate thread constantly reads data source (with needed pauses) and stores it in volatile field. Rest service justs return this field.
2. Same but in more managed way: use not separate thread but ScheduledExecuter.
3. Same but don't read data source when nobody is interested: use cache which loads data from source if it is not found. Guice cache or Caffeine would do.